# Not able to run Version garbage collection in jcr implementation

Tags: java, postgresql, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I am getting below error while running version garbage collection:

"Limit 100000 documents exceeded, reducing next collection interval to 37561439 seconds","logger_name":"org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.VersionGarbageCollector","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-3","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.DocumentStoreException: exception while reading versionGC] with root cause","logger_name":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-3","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot change transaction read-only property in the middle of a transaction.**\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.setReadOnly(PgConnection.java:693)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementCache.invoke(StatementCache.java:203)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:152)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.TrapException.invoke(TrapException.java:40)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.setReadOnly(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.rdb.RDBConnectionHandler.setReadOnly(RDBConnectionHandler.java:176)\r\n\tat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.rdb.RDBConnectionHandler.getROConnection(RDBConnectionHandler.java:61)\r\n\tat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.rdb.RDBDocumentStore.readDocumentUncached(RDBDocumentStore.java:1897)\r\n\tat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.rdb.RDBDocumentStore.readDocumentCached(RDBDocumentStore.java:1454)\r\n\tat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.rdb.RDBDocumentStore.internalCreateOrUpdate(RDBDocumentStore.java:1557)\r\n\tat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.rdb.RDBDocumentStore.createOrUpdate(RDBDocumentStore.java:367)\r\n\tat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.VersionGarbageCollector$Recommendations.setLongSetting(VersionGarbageCollector.java:1200)\r\n\tat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.VersionGarbageCollector$Recommendations.evaluate(VersionGarbageCollector.java:1156)\r\n\tat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.VersionGarbageCollector$GCJob.gc(VersionGarbageCollector.java:515)\r\n\tat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.VersionGarbageCollector$GCJob.run(VersionGarbageCollector.java:475)\r\n\tat org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.VersionGarbageCollector.gc(VersionGarbageCollector.java:144)\r\n\tat com.springernature.mango.cms.services.rest.service.ServicesController.runGC(ServicesController.java:1080)\r\n\tat com.springernature.mango.cms.services.rest.service.ServicesController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bd16ea4e.invoke()\r\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:84)\r\n\tat com.springernature.mango.cms.handler.LoggingHandler.logAround(LoggingHandler.java:108)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:616)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)\r\n\tat com.springernature.mango.cms.services.rest.service.ServicesController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a5dbc1e7.runGC()\r\n\tat

Mycode:

```
public void runGC() {
    log.info("Running garbage collection for NodeStore");
    try {
        RepositoryUtil.getDocumentNodeStore().getVersionGarbageCollector().gc(
            0,
            TimeUnit.DAYS);
    } catch (final IOException ioe) {
        log.error("Error while running Version Garbage Collection : {}", ioe);
    }

    log.info("Garbage collection execution completed");
}
```

Please let me know how to run version garbage collection properly for deleted Node in jackrabbit oak.

Below is the code to create repository and get document node store object for version garbage collection

```
private static Repository createRepo(final Map<String, String> dbDetails)
                                                                          throws DataStoreException {
    try {
        final RDBOptions options =
            new RDBOptions().tablePrefix(dbDetails.get(DB_TABLE_PREFIX)).dropTablesOnClose(
                false);
        final DataSource ds =
            RDBDataSourceFactory.forJdbcUrl(
                dbDetails.get("dbURL"),
                dbDetails.get("dbUser"),
                dbDetails.get("dbPassword"));
        final Properties properties = buildS3Properties(dbDetails);
        final S3DataStore s3DataStore = buildS3DataStore(properties);
        final DataStoreBlobStore dataStoreBlobStore = new DataStoreBlobStore(s3DataStore);
        final Whiteboard wb = new DefaultWhiteboard();

        bapRegistration =
            wb.register(
                BlobAccessProvider.class,
                (BlobAccessProvider) dataStoreBlobStore,
                properties);

        *documentNodeStore =*
            new RDBDocumentNodeStoreBuilder()
                .setBlobStore(dataStoreBlobStore)
                .setBundlingDisabled(true)
                .setRDBConnection(ds, options)
                .build();

        repository = new Jcr(documentNodeStore).with(wb).createRepository();
        return repository;
    } catch (final DataStoreException e) {
        log.error("S3 Connection could not be created." + e);
        throw new DataStoreException("S3 Connection could not be created");
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to supply more information. Oak version? PG JDBC version? What *other* code are you runnin? Is that code working fine and GC is the *only* issue?

Comment: @JulianReschke Oak version - 1.10.2, PostgreSQL 10.7 (10.7), using driver: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.2 (42.2). Above I have added code and it working fine, and yes GC is the only issue.

Comment: Is RDBDocumentStore the only user of the DataSource?

Comment: yes, RDBDocumentStore only user of the DataSource.

Comment: Well, this is strange. The only reason I can think of is that an unclosed connection is returned to the pool. You may want to upgrade Oak to 1.10.8, and if the problem persists, you should create a Jira ticket and attach everything needed to reproduce this.

Comment: I have huge data to be garbage collected, if data exceeds 100000 it throwing exception, After "Iterated through 100000 documents so far. 99878 found to be deleted" this message

Comment: You can try to set the system property org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.rdb.RDBConnectionHandler.CHECKCONNECTIONONCLOSE to "true"; this might report where the broken connection comes from.

Comment: It seems that broken connection coming from Postgres sql connection as I could see that PSQLException in above stack trace highlighted in bold. I found some fix for this in link(https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/674) but I am not sure how to use this with documentNodeStore by setting RDBConnection.

Comment: *Something* is returning a broken connection to the connection pool. Please see my previous comment.

Comment: I am not able to set system property in code, may I know how to set it?

Comment: On the command line when starting Java (-Dname=value)

Comment: I added system property and I could not see any luck. Do you know how to limit number of node to be deleted by GC?

Comment: @JulianReschke, I am not able to set collect limit to 1000000  by using below code snippet : 

final VersionGCOptions versionGCOptions = new VersionGCOptions();
versionGCOptions.withCollectLimit(1000000);
           documentNodeStore.getVersionGarbageCollector().setOptions(versionGCOptions);
log.info("versionGCOptions.collectLimit : " + versionGCOptions.collectLimit); //still printing '100000'

Comment: At this point, it would be best if you could open JIRA tickets with test cases that reproduce your problems.

Comment: OAK-8912 JIRA ticket create, I will add test cases after some time